# Create a folder and Text file based on a string in a given input file

Tags: java, substr

I have a file of 40K+ lines. Each line is of the below format.

...Some Random Text.....OWN AB .....XML.......XML....
...Some Random Text.....OWN MN .....XML.......XML....
...Some Random Text.....OWN XY .....XML.......XML....
...Some Random Text.....OWN AB .....XML.......XML....

I want to create a folder with  Whatever follows **OWN** and a text file with the contents XM...XML

There can be many lines with same OWN code. Hence the next file should be created in the existing folder.

Can you please help this in Java. 
Thank you.

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

```
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (strLine);   
      String Filename = "D:/Result/TestCase";
      Filename = Filename + "_"+ count + ".txt";
      try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( Filename )  )
        {
            out.println( strLine );
            count++;

        }


    }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for doing your work. Can you show your effort thusfar? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: What have you tried ? Hint : You are going to loop through the input file line by line, and create new file based on the contents of the given line

Comment: I tried to extract the content between the <XML> tag but I am not sure what to use.